# GraphQL variables Issue

Tags: graphql, apollo-server

this my graphql query query

```
Products($first: Int, $variantsFirst2: Int) {
  products(first: $first) {
    nodes {
      variants(first: $variantsFirst2) {
        nodes {
          id
        }
      }
    }
  }
} 
}
```

i have 2 variables and i pass the variables like this

```
{
  "first": 1,
  "variantsFirst2": 1
}
```

Now the Apollo server removes the variable variantsFirst2, when it reaches the resolver function.My graphQL schema is below.

type query {
products (first): ProductObject
}

```
type ProductObject {
  nodes: [Product!]!
}

type Product  {
   variants(
    first: Int   
  ): ProductVariantConnection!}
```

I kind of know why Apollo server removes variantsFirst2, because it is not part of schema file.
But see this working in some other application, as I cannot talk to that application developers I am asking here.